# Basic Programming in Mathematica - How to build a loop

Tags: list-manipulation, programming

I want to build a loop with the following rules:
I have a list `a={5,7,8,9,5,6,8,6,7,8}`. I want to print the mean of the first two `{5,7}`. Then the mean of the first three `{5,7,8}`, then the mean of the first four `{5,7,8,9}` and on and on. Any ideas?

Comment: Use `Table[]`, `Take[]`, and `Mean[]`.

Comment: Related/duplicate: [Alternatives to procedural loops and iterating over lists in Mathematica](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/7924/5)

Comment: It doesn't matter for your particular case, but if the list is long enough, you want to make sure that you are not recalculating sum of all numbers at every iteration. So you can figure out a recursive relation for your mean values and then use `FoldList`

Comment: @J.M. Are you planning to come up with `SparseArray` solution for this one? :)

Comment: @BlacKow, for sure, I never would have deigned to post Anton's solution… ;P

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a `SparseArray` solution (as prompted by BlacKow):

```
vecs = Table[
  SparseArray[ConstantArray[1/i, i], Length[a]], {i, 2, Length[a]}]

a.# & /@ vecs
```

Comment: +1 for perverting `SparseArray` functionality into something that scales worse than my abacus...

Comment: @ciao  Thanks! It was an interesting little challenge ...

Answer (score 6):

No need to loop, and in general you'll want to use built-in, functional idioms for readability and performance, e.g.:

```
Rest@Accumulate[a]/Range[2, Length@a]
```

will give the desired result efficiently.

Comment: In the case where one or more numbers have a weight, what can be done? For example, 5 has a weight 2 and 9 has a weight 4, the mean is estimated this way: (5*2+9*4) / (2+4) = 7.66.

Answer (score 1):

We should not try to hide that it *can* be done by indexing over `a`, and since the OP specifically asked for such a solution, I think he deserves to get one. This is what occurred to me.

```
progressiveMean[a_List] :=
  Module[{prev = a[[1]], next},
    Rest @
      Table[
        next = (a[[i]] + (i - 1) prev)/i; prev = next,
        {i, 2, Length[a]}]]

a = {5, 7, 8, 9, 5, 6, 8, 6, 7, 8};
progressiveMean[a] // N
```

> `{6., 6.66667, 7.25, 6.8, 6.66667, 6.85714, 6.75, 6.77778, 6.9}`

This is essentially the procedural version of ciao's answer, but of course not so efficient.